# How to identify records that contain a phone number

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, phone-number

I have the need to identify records in my database that contain a phone number so that I can send them on to a contact team.

Example:
tblData

- id
- comment
- dtCreate

Given this table structure, the query might be:

```
SELECT * FROM tblData WHERE comment [HeresWhereINeedHelp]
```

The comment might (and likely will) contain all sorts of other data.  An example comment:

*Yea, I had a terrible experience.  I'd like for someone to call me at 111.222.3333.  Thank you.*

The record containing this comment should be pulled in the query because it contains a phone number.

I tried an extended SPROC that enabled regex searching, but the performance was terrible.  The system is SQL Server 2012.

Many thanks for any direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look at the [`LIKE` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx). In your case, you're probably going to go for something along the lines of

```
WHERE comment LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

Since you're searching anywhere in the string, this will also take a long time to process over a large dataset - another option you might want to try is checking the comment field for a phone number when it's entered and then flagging that row using a column like `ContainsPhoneNumber (bit).` That way, you can index on that column and do faster lookups.

Comment: Additionally: This is going to be very sensitive to changes in formatting - if the phone number has different spacing like '(123) 456 - 7890', you'd have to use an additional filter to catch that.

Comment: Thanks, mikurski.  Looks like 5 will get me there since I want to find 7 digits, as well:  WHERE comment LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
OR comment LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9]__[0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
OR comment LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
OR comment LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
OR comment LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'

Answer (score 0):

I would create a separate table for phone numbers stored as 10 digit integer.
Run Regex once to parse out the phone numbers.
Index that column and you will get index seek speed.